# Iphone 7 Safari issue with text jumping

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap

I have created this static website (HTML/CSS/JS, with Bootstrap) for a client:
http://www.oiga.se

It works well on most screens, but there is a weird bug on iPhone 7 Safari.
The "Contact"/kontakt part of the page lists numbers and names of the employees, but somehow the name jumps to the right on iPhone 7.

This is how it is supposed to look:
[image]

This is how it looks:
[image]

I am very confused about this. Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: You need to add your HTML and CSS code here

Comment: Hmm.. The whole source? I'm not sure what causing this so I don't know what exactly would be the relevant code to paste here.

Comment: just add your code related to the issue. the code behind your image

Comment: And by finding the relevant code I figured it out myself;)

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue. Safari automatically turns phone numbers into anchors, and I had a float left on anchors inside of the contact-section.

Comment: nice! i will remember it for future.